# Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails - doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

My userland code:-

```
$projects = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Project::class)->findBy(['deletionDate' => new DateTime('today + 364 day')]);

foreach($projects as $project){
    $project = $this->entityManager->find('App\Entity\Project', $project->getId());
    $this->entityManager->remove($project);
}
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Here's the error:

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`foo`.`entry`, CONSTRAINT `FK_2B219D70166D1F9C` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `project` (`id`))
```

and here's what I'm attempting:-

```
class Entry
{
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Project::class, inversedBy="entries")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank
    */
    public ?Project $project;
}

class Project
{
  /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entry", mappedBy="project", cascade={"remove"})
  */
  public Collection $entries;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Doctrine itself but with the general database rule - you cannot delete rows that other rows in the database depend on.

Now, something that caught my eye was:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
```

Namely, you have `onDelete="CASCADE"`, however:

```
`FK_2B219D70166D1F9C` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `project` (`id`))
```

tells us a whole different story.

It seems that your database and your model are not in sync. Do you manage that by migrations? If so, did you run all of them?

You could try to:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

which will generate a single migration containing all the differences.

Be careful, inspect detected changes and apply them after making any necessary adjustments.

### Update:

Given that you do not manage DB changes via migrations of any sort, the only way would be to execute the `ALTER` query by hand in order to fix this issue.

Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE entry DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_2B219D70166D1F9C;
ALTER TABLE entry ADD FOREIGN KEY FK_2B219D70166D1F9C(project_id)
            REFERENCES project(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Do you manage that by migrations? - My db is generated from an sql dump. Even with the `onDelete="CASCADE"` removed, I still get the same error

Comment: That would totally make sense. Can you inspect that SQL dump? It should probably not have `REFERENCES project(id)) ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: yep, I do a search in the dump file for the string `REFERENCES project(id)) ON DELETE CASCADE` with no results. Just to rewind a little. The reason I adjusted my annotations was since the comments on here suggested using this construct when deleting records across multiple tables with doctrine. thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer with queries

Comment: You're welcome :) You should definitely try investing some time on starting with Doctrine Migrations. The overhead seems high at the beginning, but any subsequent need to change the schema pays off...